# QML Combobox popup not updating

Tags: combobox, qml, popup, dropdown

The issue is when I change the model of QML editable Combobox the popup list doesn't update. Appending and removing items from model does display correctly, but changing existing item only affects model.
I've found a similar question and it said that this bug had been fixed, but in Qt6 which I'm using I still have that problem.

```
ComboBox
      {
        id: comboBoxID
        textRole: text
        currentIndex: 0
        editable: true
        model: ListModel
        {
          id: listModelID
          ListElement {text: "test0"}
          ListElement {text: "test1"}
        }

        onActivated:
        {
          console.log('onActivated() model.get(',currentIndex,').text:', model.get(currentIndex).text);
        }
        onAccepted:
        {
          console.log('onAccepted() editText:', editText);
          model.get(currentIndex).text = editText;
//          model.remove(currentIndex);
//          model.insert(currentIndex, {text: editText})
        }
      }
```

So here for example when I change first item to "tes" it changes in model, but in popup list first item is still named "test0". Also when I choose "test0" after edit, Combobox displays me correct "tes".
[image: QML Combobox pupup issue]

But if I use .append(), .remove() or .insert() methods popup list updates correctly. So I think that .get() or .set() methods simply don't emit some update signal for popup component, but which one?

Comment: I notice that there aren't any documented symbols on the `ListModel` component. It might be that the changed signals don't exist. The reason removing and inserting works is because the `count` property changes, forcing re-evaluation.

Comment: If it works this way, changing `count` property, then I don't really understand how exactly. I tried editing existing element AND adding new one - new one showed up correctly, but edited didn't change in popup list. This way I presume changing `count` property doesn't update whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) QML type is essentially a very thin implementation of a [QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html), but it is super basic. It does not implement any smart logic for emitting `dataChanged` signals when new data is set.

To be honest, for these reasons, I rarely use the `ListModel` and nearly always prefer to implement my own custom list model. There's a [guide for how to do that](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference).

There is a hack you could use, if you really want to use the out-of-the box QML `ListModel`, though. You could manually call the signals on the model, forcing the update to happen. For instance, calling the `modelReset` signal will force every binding to the model to re-evaluate:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ComboBox {
    editable: true
    model: ListModel{
        ListElement {text: "test0"}
        ListElement {text: "test1"}
    }
    onAccepted: {
        model.set(currentIndex, {text: editText});
        model.modelReset();
    }
}
```